# Impute missing dates and values using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a file named df that has the following values:

```
  Date              Available        Used        Total       Free
 
  06072019          5                19          24          5
  06202019          14               10          24          6           
  07072019          6                16          24          6
  07202019          20               4           24          20
  08072019          23               1           24          23
```

I am missing the date 08202019 and am looking to impute the missing values with the average of the existing data that I have.

This is what I am currently doing:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt


df.groupby([df.index.date]).transform(lambda x: x.fill(x.mean()))
```

However, I know that some of the syntax is not correct here and would like some suggestions.

Comment: Please accept the best solution by me or another as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension to get the means of all the columns excluding the first date column and create a transposed dataframe, which will eseentially be one row. Then concat this new 1-row dataframe with the main dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '06-07-2019',
  1: '06-20-2019',
  2: '07-07-2019',
  3: '07-20-2019',
  4: '08-07-2019'},
 'Available': {0: 5, 1: 14, 2: 6, 3: 20, 4: 23},
 'Used': {0: 19, 1: 10, 2: 16, 3: 4, 4: 1},
 'Total': {0: 24, 1: 24, 2: 24, 3: 24, 4: 24},
 'Free': {0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 6, 3: 20, 4: 23}})
s = pd.DataFrame([df[col].mean() for col in df.columns[1:]]).T
s.columns = df.columns[1:]
s['Date'] = '08-20-2019'
df_new = pd.concat([df, s])
df_new
Out[1]: 
         Date  Available  Used  Total  Free
0  06-07-2019        5.0  19.0   24.0   5.0
1  06-20-2019       14.0  10.0   24.0   6.0
2  07-07-2019        6.0  16.0   24.0   6.0
3  07-20-2019       20.0   4.0   24.0  20.0
4  08-07-2019       23.0   1.0   24.0  23.0
0  08-20-2019       13.6  10.0   24.0  12.0
```

In regards to your comment, you could create a `missing_dates` list and everything else will be automatic with the loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '06-07-2019',
  1: '06-20-2019',
  2: '07-07-2019',
  3: '07-20-2019',
  4: '08-07-2019'},
 'Available': {0: 5, 1: 14, 2: 6, 3: 20, 4: 23},
 'Used': {0: 19, 1: 10, 2: 16, 3: 4, 4: 1},
 'Total': {0: 24, 1: 24, 2: 24, 3: 24, 4: 24},
 'Free': {0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 6, 3: 20, 4: 23}})
s = pd.DataFrame([df[col].mean() for col in df.columns[1:]]).T
t = s
missing_dates = ['08-20-2019' , '08-30-2019']
for i in range(len(missing_dates) - 1):
    t = t.append(s)
t.columns = df.columns[1:]
t['Date'] = missing_dates
df_new = pd.concat([df, t])
df_new
Out[2]: 
         Date  Available  Used  Total  Free
0  06-07-2019        5.0  19.0   24.0   5.0
1  06-20-2019       14.0  10.0   24.0   6.0
2  07-07-2019        6.0  16.0   24.0   6.0
3  07-20-2019       20.0   4.0   24.0  20.0
4  08-07-2019       23.0   1.0   24.0  23.0
0  08-20-2019       13.6  10.0   24.0  12.0
0  08-30-2019       13.6  10.0   24.0  12.0
```

Comment: Let me try this, and if I wanted to have multiple dates, say, 08-30-2019, could I add them within this? s['Date'] = '08-20-2019' , '08-30-2019'....etc?

Comment: @Lynnette , yes, but would the mean be duplicated down? E.G. mean of `Available` column is 13.6 repeated down.

Answer (score 2):

Consider your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%m%d%Y")
df = df.set_index("Date")

print(df)
            Available  Used  Total  Free
Date                                    
2019-06-07          5    19     24     5
2019-06-20         14    10     24     6
2019-07-07          6    16     24     6
2019-07-20         20     4     24    20
2019-08-07         23     1     24    23
```

You can create a list of missing dates, convert it to a pandas datetime array, create a new index that you'll then fill the `na` with the column means.

```
missing_dates = ["2019-08-20", "2019-09-07", "2019-09-20"]
missing_dates = pd.to_datetime(missing_dates)
new_index = df.index.union(missing_dates)

df = df.reindex(new_index).fillna(df.mean(numeric_only=True))

print(df)
            Available  Used  Total  Free
2019-06-07        5.0  19.0   24.0   5.0
2019-06-20       14.0  10.0   24.0   6.0
2019-07-07        6.0  16.0   24.0   6.0
2019-07-20       20.0   4.0   24.0  20.0
2019-08-07       23.0   1.0   24.0  23.0
2019-08-20       13.6  10.0   24.0  12.0
2019-09-07       13.6  10.0   24.0  12.0
2019-09-20       13.6  10.0   24.0  12.0
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to check for dates that are non-existent in the data, you can try this:

```py
# suppose data series goes from '2020-09-30' to '2020-10-04' and data on some dates may be missing.
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    dict(datetime=['09302020','10012020','10042020'],
         val1 = [1,3,5], 
         val2 = [6,10,12]))
df.datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime, format='%m%d%Y')

print(df)

dates_missing = pd.date_range(start = '2020-09-30', end = '2020-10-04' ).difference(df.datetime)

val_means = {col: df[col].mean() for col in list(df.columns) if col != 'datetime'}

df = df.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    dict(datetime=dates_missing, **val_means)))

df = df.sort_values(by=['datetime'])

df
```